# Prevent a plus sign from being appended to Linux build

Tags: linux-kernel, compiling

The kernel build system like to append `+` to the kernel's local version string whenever it detects that the source tree is version controlled with Git. I can prevent this annoying modification to `LOCALVERSION` from taking place by running `make LOCALVERSION=` whenever I am compiling some part of the kernel, but I don't if that will override `LOCALVERSION` as it is set in the configuration file and I don't want to have to include that every time I build the kernel. I do not want to modify the code of the build system to achieve this desired end. How can I make this happen? Is there another configuration option?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19333918/dont-add-to-linux-kernel-version